Invariance of the Laplacian under orthogonal transformations
I am struggling to solve the following question. Consider the function $u(x, y)$ which is twice-differentiable in its arguments and in arguments $\xi$ and $\eta$ obtained by the following linear transformation of $x$ and $y$:
$$
\xi = ax - by, \quad \eta = bx + ay,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real constants and $a^2 + b^2 = 1$. Show that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \eta^2}.
$$
Any ideas?
